# Blazor - Circular references - serialization and deserialization default options

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly

In a Blazor WebAssembly app I have one single server side method that returns results with circular references.

I found out that I can handle this situation on the server side by adding the following:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
    });
```

and on the client side:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions() { ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve };
var r = await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<MyObject>>($"api/mycontroller/mymethod", options);
```

Unfortunately this way reference handling is enabled for *every method* on server. This introduces "$id" keys in almost all my methods results.

This would force me to change *every* client call to introduce `ReferenceHandler.Preserve` option.

Is there a way to specify `ReferenceHandler.Preserve` for *some* methods only (server side) or alternatively an option to force `ReferenceHandler.Preserve` for *every* `GetFromJsonAsync` (client side)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-6.0) in your sever . In custom middleware , you can put the method in it and do judge the URL passed by blazor. If the url meets the requirements, execute the method in the middleware, If not ,Just ignore this method.